# REST API Design for systems with multiple companies or organizations

Tags: rest, grails

Most of the examples I see implement REST URL patterns like `http://www.app.com/books/1` to access a book with ID 1 or `http://www.app.com/books` to access all the books.

That's great, but commonly I work on applications that support multiple companies. For example, Company ABC has 2 users and Company DEF has 2 users. A user from company **ABC** creates a **book with id 100**. Now when a RESTful call comes in from a user at company **DEF**:

`http://www.app.com/books/100`

there would need to be an Access exception, or

`http://www.app.com/books`

would only list all books belonging to DEF (not the new book with id 100). For many entities, like Book, the company ID is part of the table, but for other entities that may not be the case. For example, if there was a REST operation for one chapter in a book, `http://www.app.com/chapter/333` the chapter table would have a foreign key reference to the book but not the company.

What would best practices be for managing access to this resource? If somebody from DEF tried to access a chapter from ABC I would have to construct a query to join the chapter to the book to verify the company id was valid.

I'm using Grails 3.x where most of this logic is abstracted and thinks happen "automagically". So a URL that comes in for a specific book ID is returned automatically and the request to list all returns every book in the database. It seems that to proceed I would have to override most of this automatic functionality and implement my own security, perhaps in the service layer where the company id would be a required parameter for every operation. Does that sound reasonable?

Is there an established best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: For the most part, we add security to the query based on the user's logged in info (using SpringSecurityPlugin) on the server side (the client never even knows it's part of the query).  Simplistically, whenever we'd want list(), we'd use findByCompany(), and findByIdAndCompany, or add Company as a criteria in all the REST-requested searches.  Part of the Book domain would be a Company (or set of Companies) which created it/has access.

Comment: Exactly - use SpringSecurity to authenticate each request via token in request header. After that you can implement any logic you want to and your app will know which company is asking for data. Check: **org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core** and **org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest**

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it fits your needs but it's interesting to know there is an ACL plugin written by Burt Beckwith :

[Spring Security ACL Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-acl/v3/index.html)